# How to only extract text from divs using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a HTML-page containg a DIV like that:

```
<div class="item-content">
    <p>Bla bla bla <em>Name</em> Ba bla bla.</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla.</p>
    <p> <a href="https://example.com/link.htm"><img src="/image.gif" height="620" width="620" /></a></p>
    <p><style> p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 18.0px...} </style></p>
    <p>Bla bla bla <em>Name</em> Ba bla bla.</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla.</p>
</div>
```

My goal is to get a string with only "Bla bla bla Name bla bla bla ... Name bla bla"
No style no nothing.

For doing so I use that code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('ogn2.html', 'r')

html_doc = f.read()

f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find(attrs={"class": "item-content"})

b = a.find_all("p")

text = ""
a = 0

for p in b:
    a = a + 1
    print(a, p.string)
    if p.string and not p.style:
         text = text + " " + p.string

print(text)
```

Using this I manage to exclude the `<a>` and the `<style>` but unfortunately BeautifulSoup does not return a text if the `<p>`-line contains a tag like `<em>`.

What do I do wrong? Or maybe how can a achieve that in a smarter way (not by reading line by line and concatenate them again)?

EDIT:

What I miss are the paragrapghs containing the  tags:

```
<p>Bla bla bla <em>Name</em> Ba bla bla.</p>
```

So my desired outcome should be the plain text of the whole  without any additional tags in between.

Comment: *"unfortunately BeautifulSoup does not return a text if the dot"*? What the dot?

Comment: You need to use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for any HTML tags. Also could you explain the expected and actual output

Comment: Try `p.getText()` instead of `p.string`.

Comment: Hi Martin - my xmas hero - that did the trick!! Perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about with filter, something like below,

```
 def filter_tags(element):
   if element.parent.name in ['style']:
     return False
   return True


 texts = filter(filter_tags, soup.find(attrs={'class': 'item-content'}).find_all(text=True)) # This will return list of texts

 # You may apply join to concatenate.
 " ".join(texts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
entries = []
for p in b:
    if not p.style and p.text.strip():
        entries.append(p.text)

text = " ".join(entries)
print(text)
```

The extra condition `p.text.strip()` makes sure that lines only containing whitespaces are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<div class="item-content">
    <p>Bla bla bla <em>Name</em> Ba bla bla.</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla.</p>
    <p> <a href="https://example.com/link.htm"><img src="/image.gif" height="620" width="620" /></a></p>
    <p><style> p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 18.0px...} </style></p>
    <p>Bla bla bla <em>Name</em> Ba bla bla.</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla.</p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
[item.extract() for item in soup.select("style")]
items = "".join([item.text for item in soup.select(".item-content p")])
print(items)
```

Output:

```
Bla bla bla Name Ba bla bla.Bla bla bla. Bla bla bla Name Ba bla bla.Bla bla bla.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try p.getText() instead of p.string. – Martin Schmelzer

This was the easiest way for me!

Thank you Martin!!!

Comment: Just to note that `.getText` is part of the deprecated interface - you really should be and get into the habit of using: `.get_text` in BS4 as it's probably not going to be around much longer.